# perl - using HTML to extract data

Tags: regex, perl, perl-module

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $temp_path =  $ENV{'TEMP'}."\\html\\globals_func.html";   

// prints as C:\Users\Rockstar\Appdata\Local\Temp\html\globals_func.html

my $url = $temp_path;
my $page = get($url) or die $!;
my $p = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content($page);
```

I get error: protocol 'c' is not supported

I get correct output when

```
my $url='file:///C:/Users/Rockstar/AppData/Local/Temp/html/globals_func.html';
```

As I want to make it run across all systems I am using global environment variable.

how do I change '\' to '/' in $url by using regex or is there any other way?

HTML file is present locally in the system itself.

Comment: There's no need to use `LWP` for slurping a local file. Use `File::Slurp` or do it manually using `open($fh,...)` and `<$fh>`, then you can use the path as is.

Comment: okay. will look into that too.

Comment: i used File::Slurp and its so simple without using so much of regex .just use read_line($file_path) and now my program also runs on linux."file:///" was causing trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $temp_path =  $ENV{'TEMP'}."\\html\\globals_func.html";   

// prints as C:\Users\Rockstar\Appdata\Local\Temp\html\globals_func.html

$temp_path=~tr/\\/\//; # Replaces backward slashes with forward slashes

$temp_path='file://'.$temp_path; # Appends path with file://

my $url = $temp_path;
my $page = get($url) or die $!;
my $p = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content($page);
```

Comment: it works fine. but you missed a '/'. it should be $temp_path='file:///'.$temp_path;

Answer (score 3):

Use [Path::Class::URI](http://p3rl.org/Path%3a%3aClass%3a%3aURI) to create cross-platform `file://` URIs.